# trying to find a hidden string in a 32-bit ELF

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, elf

Don't worry, I'm not going to ask for the answer.

I'm trying to find a hidden string (maybe an email?) in a simple 1 function 32-bit exe

I've already run strings on the file, nothing useful.

I've decompiled the file to ASCII and found the main function.

File shows that it is a GCC executable.

here is the asm of the main function:

```
        ; ================ B E G I N N I N G   O F   P R O C E D U R E ================

        ; Variables:
        ;    arg_0: int, 4


             main:
080489cc         lea        ecx, dword [esp+arg_0]                              ; Begin of unwind block (FDE at 0x80d6cb8), DATA XREF=_start+23
080489d0         and        esp, 0xfffffff0
080489d3         push       dword [ecx-4]
080489d6         push       ebp
080489d7         mov        ebp, esp
080489d9         push       esi
080489da         push       ebx
080489db         push       ecx
080489dc         sub        esp, 0x2c
080489df         call       __x86.get_pc_thunk.cx                               ; __x86.get_pc_thunk.cx
080489e4         add        ecx, 0xa261c
080489ea         mov        eax, dword [gs:0x14]
080489f0         mov        dword [ebp-0x1c], eax
080489f3         xor        eax, eax
080489f5         mov        eax, esp
080489f7         mov        esi, eax
080489f9         mov        dword [ebp-0x2c], 0x15
08048a00         mov        eax, dword [ebp-0x2c]
08048a03         lea        edx, dword [eax-1]
08048a06         mov        dword [ebp-0x28], edx
08048a09         shl        eax, 0x2
08048a0c         lea        edx, dword [eax+3]
08048a0f         mov        eax, 0x10
08048a14         sub        eax, 0x1
08048a17         add        eax, edx
08048a19         mov        ebx, 0x10
08048a1e         mov        edx, 0x0
08048a23         div        ebx
08048a25         imul       eax, eax, 0x10
08048a28         sub        esp, eax
08048a2a         mov        eax, esp
08048a2c         add        eax, 0x3
08048a2f         shr        eax, 0x2
08048a32         shl        eax, 0x2
08048a35         mov        dword [ebp-0x24], eax
08048a38         mov        eax, dword [ebp-0x24]
08048a3b         mov        dword [eax], 0x2391
08048a41         mov        eax, dword [ebp-0x24]
08048a44         mov        dword [eax+4], 0x239d
08048a4b         mov        eax, dword [ebp-0x24]
08048a4e         mov        dword [eax+8], 0x239d
08048a55         mov        eax, dword [ebp-0x24]
08048a58         mov        dword [eax+0xc], 0x2399
08048a5f         mov        eax, dword [ebp-0x24]
08048a62         mov        dword [eax+0x10], 0x239c
08048a69         mov        eax, dword [ebp-0x24]
08048a6c         mov        dword [eax+0x14], 0x2363
08048a73         mov        eax, dword [ebp-0x24]
08048a76         mov        dword [eax+0x18], 0x2358
08048a7d         mov        eax, dword [ebp-0x24]
08048a80         mov        dword [eax+0x1c], 0x2358
08048a87         mov        eax, dword [ebp-0x24]
08048a8a         mov        dword [eax+0x20], 0x2390
08048a91         mov        eax, dword [ebp-0x24]
08048a94         mov        dword [eax+0x24], 0x2398
08048a9b         mov        eax, dword [ebp-0x24]
08048a9e         mov        dword [eax+0x28], 0x2398
08048aa5         mov        eax, dword [ebp-0x24]
08048aa8         mov        dword [eax+0x2c], 0x2357
08048aaf         mov        eax, dword [ebp-0x24]
08048ab2         mov        dword [eax+0x30], 0x2390
08048ab9         mov        eax, dword [ebp-0x24]
08048abc         mov        dword [eax+0x34], 0x2395
08048ac3         mov        eax, dword [ebp-0x24]
08048ac6         mov        dword [eax+0x38], 0x2358
08048acd         mov        eax, dword [ebp-0x24]
08048ad0         mov        dword [eax+0x3c], 0x2377
08048ad7         mov        eax, dword [ebp-0x24]
08048ada         mov        dword [eax+0x40], 0x235e
08048ae1         mov        eax, dword [ebp-0x24]
08048ae4         mov        dword [eax+0x44], 0x2380
08048aeb         mov        eax, dword [ebp-0x24]
08048aee         mov        dword [eax+0x48], 0x237a
08048af5         mov        eax, dword [ebp-0x24]
08048af8         mov        dword [eax+0x4c], 0x2381
08048aff         mov        eax, dword [ebp-0x24]
08048b02         mov        dword [eax+0x50], 0x23a3
08048b09         mov        eax, dword [ebp-0x2c]
08048b0c         sub        esp, 0xc
08048b0f         push       eax                                                 ; argument #1 for method __libc_malloc
08048b10         mov        ebx, ecx
08048b12         call       __libc_malloc                                       ; __libc_malloc
08048b17         add        esp, 0x10
08048b1a         add        eax, 0x1
08048b1d         mov        dword [ebp-0x20], eax
08048b20         mov        dword [ebp-0x30], 0x0
08048b27         jmp        loc_8048b44
```

lines 08048a35 - 08048b09  looks like it's moving 1 character at a time, which I'm positive it's the string.

The question here is, could someone help me figure out what those characters are? They aren't ASCII encoding, and I'm not sure how ASM really does stuff like character encoding, so maybe I'm just not seeing it. Maybe it's encrypted?

I'm new to this, and don't really know the best approach. Thanks!

Comment: It's moving `dword`, which is 8 bytes at a time.

Comment: @Barmar: on x86 dword means 4 bytes...

Comment: Of course, that explains why it goes `eax+4`, `eax+8`, etc.

Comment: @barmar I was expecting 8-bit character codes. Am I wrong here?

Comment: What's the actual question here?

Comment: @barmar how to use gdb to get the byte value for each line, I can then try and see if those match up with UTF characters

Comment: @dprogramz: you don't really need to read the registers, it's there in plain sight to see, they are even already sorted. But it looks like it's populating an array of 32-bit integer values with those bizarre numbers (which aren't straight ASCII values).

Comment: Presumably the important details are in code you omitted. At the end you can see it's allocating some memory, that's probably used for the decoded address.

Comment: @MatteoItalia ah, ok, that makes sense, sorry I thought each line was overwriting the value. I can't seem to find any reference to what those values might be referring too. I'll delete this question if there isn't enough information here

Comment: @Jester I'll dive back into the assembly and try and follow to see where it's going and update the question or delete it if i can't figure it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sequence

```
08048a38         mov        eax, dword [ebp-0x24]
08048a3b         mov        dword [eax], 0x2391
08048a41         mov        eax, dword [ebp-0x24]
08048a44         mov        dword [eax+4], 0x239d
```

(and so on) is writing 0x2391, 0x239d, ... at consecutive locations in an array of 32 bit integers (see the contiguous offsets spaced by 4 bytes) whose pointer was passed as a parameter (the pointer value is loaded - inexplicably each and every time - from ebp *minus* something). Ultimately its content is going to be:

```
0x2391
0x239d
0x239d
0x2399
0x239c
0x2363
0x2358
0x2358
0x2390
0x2398
0x2398
0x2357
0x2390
0x2395
0x2358
0x2377
0x235e
0x2380
0x237a
0x2381
0x23a3
```

Now, this isn't ASCII, but the repetition of the second and third element (plus other repetitions later) and the fact that they are all pretty much in the same range made me think that they must all be encoded in the same simple way, presumably a summation or xor with some fixed value (the always identical top 0x23 byte was a dead giveaway); so, since the rest of the code (where presumably this array is decoded) is missing from your question, I just guessed and tried to subtract the same value to them all to make them go back to the ASCII range.

My first guess was that the repeated number above (0x239d) had to be an `l` (which often go in couples in English). Hence, I needed a number such that 0x239d would become an `l` (ASCII 108); 0x239d - 108 = 9009, and that's what I subtracted to every character. The result was all ASCII (encouraging - if the scheme was something more complicated I would have gotten unreadable random garbage besides the two `l`), but nonsensical.

I opted for a brute force approach (the most reasonable cases are just 62 - uppercase, lowercase and numbers - and an exhaustive search with this method would be 256 cases at most, still manageable with visual inspection) and tried some similar numbers - all stuff that resulted in ASCII characters, but hopefully more sensible.

And indeed, once I reached 9001:

```
In [18]: [chr(int(x,16)-9001) for x in s.split()]
Out[18]: 
['h',
 't',
 't',
 'p',
 's',
 ':',
 '/',
 '/',
 'g',
 'o',
 'o',
 '.',
 'g',
 'l',
 '/',
 'N',
 '5',
 'W',
 'Q',
 'X',
 'z']
```

(`s` here is a string containing the content of the second code block of this post, the one with all the array values)

Have fun with the next level of your game. :-)

---

Incidentally, that assembly is truly horrible. Some of it, such as the continue reload of the same value from the stack to registers

```
mov eax, dword [ebp-0x24]
```

would make me think about a non-optimized, debugger-friendly build; OTOH, there is stuff that doesn't really seem to come from a compiler:

```
mov        eax, 0x10
sub        eax, 0x1
```

Here even compiling at a modest level of optimization constant propagation would have yielded `mov eax, 0xf`, or, at `-O0`, it would have been performed on the stack, not in registers, to aid source-level single-stepping.

```
mov        ebx, 0x10
mov        edx, 0x0
div        ebx
imul       eax, eax, 0x10
```

This is braindead on multiple levels; you'll never see a compiler emitting `mov edx, 0x0` *in general* - even at `-O0` zeroing a register is pretty much always `xor edx, edx`. Also, there is some confusion about the data types: first an unsigned `div`, then a signed `imul` (it maps to something like `((int)((unsigned)(foo)/16))*16`, which I find unlikely).

But most importantly gcc will never emit a `div` or a `mul` for a division/multiplication by 16; [it transforms them to a shift even at `-O0`](https://godbolt.org/g/8dSVb6); [clang is the same](https://godbolt.org/g/j1CcMc) (although at `-O0` it will still emit an `idiv` for a signed division instead of the shift + sign-bit twiddling used at higher optimization levels).

Finally, if the input value is unsigned (as per the `div`), this whole thing boils down to masking away the low 4 bits, so all this mess could simply be
`and eax, 0xfffffff0`.

So, it seems to me that this is handwritten code by someone not very experienced with assembly; this kind of thing doesn't even seem "intentional difficulty" thrown in to make disassembling harder - the code is quite straightforward, it's just very naive.

Comment: To make matters worse, that's not even an email address /o\

Comment: @Jester: ahah, true! And to make them doubly worse, initially I posted the joined output for compactness (i.e. the output of `''.join(chr(int(x,16)-9001) for x in s.split())`), but it was refused because it is an URL shortener, even if in a code block. Those filters are quite aggressive!

Comment: @MatteoItalia if this is some sort of CrackMe, the "horribility" of assembly might be intentional. Anyway, good job :).

Comment: @MatteoItalia thank you so much! what a good explanation! I was making progress on the array to ASCII encoding theory, but got lost. Could I ask, what made you think to subtract 9009, and then 9001?

Comment: @dprogramz: I wanted to subtract a number such that 0x239d (that was repeated twice) would become an `l` (ASCII 108); 0x239d - 108 = 9009, so that's what I subtracted to every character. The result was all ASCII (encouraging - if the scheme was something more complicated I would have gotten unreadable random garbage besides the two `l`), but nonsensical. So, I opted for a brute force approach (the most reasonable cases are just 62) and tried some similar numbers - all stuff that resulted in ASCII characters, but hopefully more sensible. Once I reached 9001, the string above appeared; jackpot!

Comment: @itachi: eeh the intentional difficulty from a capable programmer is usually more subtle; on one hand here it keeps on reloading the registers (`mov eax, dword [ebp-0x24]` is repeated dozens of times for no reason), and can come from no optimizations; but stuff like zeroing out registers in stupid ways (`mov edx, 0` before a `div` - use `cdq`!), using a `div` to divide by 16 (use `shr eax, 4`!), only to re-multiply the result by 16 (so he just wanted `and eax, 0xfffffff0`), braindead sequences such as `mov eax, 0x10` `sub eax, 0x1` and so on seem very strange from a compiler.

Comment: Kind of like the conclusion "This code is so bad that is must have been written by a human."  :-)

Comment: @BoPersson: heh, that's indeed one way to put it! Still, compilers do generate bad code occasionally, but generally it's a different flavor of badness. :-)

Comment: @MatteoItalia genius!  Makes total sense, and valuable knowledge to take with me. FYI, the link it revealed was to a website that needed to be hacked. I was able to figure that part out on my own. Thank you again (and to all the other stackoverflow peeps) for the help TO LEARN. that's why i love this place! :)

Comment: @dprogramz: glad it helped and was useful to learn, that's exactly the point :-) ; I hope to see more questions of this kind around, they are always fun to tackle.

Comment: @MatteoItalia would you mind obfuscating the URL in your answer. They were impressed that I was the first person to think to crowd source help for the answer. I think I made my question non-specific enough, but just afraid of giving it completely away via a keyword search ;)

Comment: @dprogramz: er... I don't think it would be particularly ethical; besides, it's already pretty much obfuscated - each character is on its line between single quotes, you cannot really search this easily through a "normal" search engine, try it for yourself.

Comment: *even at `-O0` zeroing a register is pretty much always `xor edx, edx`*: actually gcc only looks for that flag-clobbering peephole optimization at `-O2` and higher, strangely not even `-O1` https://godbolt.org/g/K732qR.  But clang/MSVC do it at `-O0`. And BTW, `cdq` before `div` is usually an error, unless you know the range of your dividend.  `cdq` -> `idiv` vs. `edx=0` -> `div`.  I agree that `mov   eax, 0x10 / sub eax, 1` looks unlikely, though; `gcc -O0` doesn't optimize between statements, but we can rule that out because the value stays in `eax` (and both operands are immediates).  MSVC?

Comment: `call    __x86.get_pc_thunk.cx` is a pretty much iron-clad guarantee that the whole thing wasn't written by a newbie.  That's compiler-generated 32-bit PIC / PIE code, by either gcc or clang (or ICC?), and no sane newbie would do that on purpose.  But maybe someone started with compiler output and added or changed some instructions by hand, because IDK how to explain the `div` with registers loaded with immediates.  If they were stored to memory and reloaded, it would be obvious: `unsigned divisor = 16;  a = b / divisor;`  But within the same statement, `-O0` doesn't stop optimization.

Comment: **I figured it out: the `mov/sub` immediate, and `div` / `imul` immediate matches `gcc -O0` code-gen for `__builtin_alloca` or a C99 VLA https://godbolt.org/g/W3FMMC** (notice the `sub        esp, eax` right after `imul`).  The compiler is rounding up the stack offset to a multiple of 16 to ESP stays aligned (and/or so the allocation itself is aligned by 16), and its canned sequence apparently gets expanded too late for the optimization pass that turns division in the source code into shifts when compiled with `-O0`.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Woah, that's seriously bad code for a compiler, I'm impressed - I wouldn't have expected that the peephole optimizer was the only guard against such horror. :-D *`call __x86.get_pc_thunk.cx` is a pretty much iron-clad guarantee that the whole thing wasn't written by a newbie* agreed, my idea was actually that it was a regular C function with the core written in (obfuscated?) assemby to show l33t h4kerz skills. *And BTW, `cdq` before `div` is usually an error* yep, I thought about that afterwards but could no longer edit the comment, I just wrote it correctly in the edited answer.